# Mysql copying from varchar column to a decimal coulmn

Tags: mysql, database-design, triggers, varchar, decimal

I have a column in MySQL  table (First table)  has varchar data type,  I used JDBC driver to insert data of numerical data type on the mentioned column .

Why I choose varchar data type of this type?
Because I failed to insert values in numerical column with JDBC.

However I decide to create another table (Second table) that has a column of decimal data type  .

Each value inserted in first table varchar column  should be  inserted directly
into the second table decimal column.

I have two  questions :-

It's the best solution to use a trigger to copy from varchar column to decimal column?

And if I do that could the values in the decimal column ordered ascending correctly?

Any advice please?

Answer (score 1):

Simply copy it.

tbl1 has x VARCHAR(...)
tbl2 has x DECIMAL(...) (or INT or FLOAT or ...)

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (..., x, ...)
    SELECT ..., x, ... FROM tbl1;
```

Strings (eg, VARCHARs) are automatically converted to numeric values, and vice versa.  There are many caveats:

- '123.456' --> `DECIMAL(9,2)` will store 123.46
- '123abc' --> 123 (decimal/int/float)
- 'abc' --> 0
- '$123' --> 0
- '123,456' --> 123
- '1e3' --> 1000 (I think)

You could even do `ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN x DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL;`, or something like that, to convert it in place.  (Please experiment with it before trying on the real table.)

Comment: Do I need to trigger to convert copy  values inserted in table 1 to table 2 In future? and it's the best idea to use trigger in this case?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I don't see the need for a trigger, nor for two tables.  First fix the existing table to use int/decimal/whatever.  Then simply insert directly into it.  The examples above show what happens if you try to insert ill-formed numeric strings.  Do you have any naughty strings?

Comment: If you are going to transition from table 1 to table 2, a table 1 trigger is a good idea to keep table 2 up to date during the transition period. Once the transition is complete, the trigger will no longer be necessary. As it will be a trigger on table 1, it will just be retired along with the table.

Comment: Table one is for accepting data inserted via  JDBC ,Table two for showing data ordered ascending , my idea about trigger is to copy values inserted into table one directly to table two without manually operation from end users so  why I don't need to after insert trigger?

Comment: If you change the datatype on Table one, the numbers will be converted as you `INSERT` them.  And you don't need the trigger or Table two.  (Unless I am still missing something.)

Comment: I failed to insert into table one via java JDBC  driver   if data type  is decimal !!!

Comment: How will you deal with the "fail" in the Trigger?